# Ubuntu 20.04 Server Mate Desktop / Remove Shutdown Icon/function for all User

Tags: server

How can I disable/delete the Shutdown icon/function on StartMenu on Ubuntu 20.04 Server with Mate Desktop?

[image: Mate Desktop Menu]

That one is not working:

```
 $ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-shutdown-menuitem true <br>  
 $ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-restart-menuitem true <br>
 $ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-menuitem true <br>
 $ gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false <br>
```

`disable-shutdown.pkla` on `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d` or `50-locale.d` are also not working:

```
[Disable lightdm PowerMgmt]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions; org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Is there a solution?